# How do I retrieve HTML for content?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, html-parsing, mechanize, helper

I am trying to write code that would take a user-input URL and print that page's HTML content to the screen. The goal is to eventually create a script that will organize all of the text on the page.

How would I edit the code below to accomplish retrieving the HTML?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('http://google.com').search("p.posted")
print ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want the `.body` method:

`puts page.body`